# Simple Format of cscript invoke-command with a variable and argument in ScriptBlock

Tags: powershell, format, invoke-command

I have this "simple" script I am trying to run with an embedded variable in the path name, I have tried with and without the + and quotes around the whole thing, I cannot seem to get a variable to work in the path.  If I run it like this, it outputs to C:\Scripts\Audit instead of to C:\Scripts\Audit\20161229_Audit\GPO_Reports.  Can you not have variable in a ScriptBlock, I have seen comments on using an ArgumentList but I am not quite sure how to do this when a variable is to be used within a path name.

```
$Date = Get-Date -format yyyyMMdd
Invoke-Command -ComputerName localhost -ScriptBlock { cscript "c:\program files\GPMC\Scripts\GetReportsForAllGPOs.wsf" "C:\Scripts\Audit\"+$date+"_Audit\GPO_Reports /domain:contuso.local" }
```

Comment: `$date` -> `$using:date`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass the *argumentlist* inside the *scriptblock* since its not in the scope.

**Instead Of:**

```
$Date = Get-Date -format yyyyMMdd
Invoke-Command -ComputerName localhost -ScriptBlock { cscript "c:\program files\GPMC\Scripts\GetReportsForAllGPOs.wsf" "C:\Scripts\Audit\"+$date+"_Audit\GPO_Reports /domain:contuso.local" }
```

**DO This:**

```
$Date = Get-Date -format yyyyMMdd
Invoke-Command -ComputerName localhost -ScriptBlock {param($Date) cscript "c:\program files\GPMC\Scripts\GetReportsForAllGPOs.wsf" "C:\Scripts\Audit\$($date)_Audit\GPO_Reports /domain:contuso.local" } -ArgumentList $Date
```

Comment: That tries to add the  /domain:contuso.local into the path name instead of as a parameter but does add the variable correctly.  The path 'C:\Scripts\Audit\20161229_Audit\GPO_Reports /domain:contuso.local' could not be found.
Verify the path exists.

Comment: I see, `Invoke-Command -ComputerName localhost -ScriptBlock {param($Date) cscript "c:\program files\GPMC\Scripts\GetReportsForAllGPOs.wsf" "C:\Scripts\Audit\$($date)_Audit\GPO_Reports" " /domain:contuso.local"  } -ArgumentList $Date`

Comment: Yes, I am not considering the code inside the script block. I thought the main issue you had in passing the date inside the block. Why are you adding the `/domain:`  That part could you please cross check because in the complete path it won't accept anything with colon and / , unless its a parameter

Comment: @pinchepooch : Ya now its fine. :)

Comment: I guess I don't have to, that is an optional argument for the script but is not necessary, I guess it was just ignoring it, thanks.